# 18.04: Dual display malfunction on Thinkpad T460, works OK w/ Windows 10

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, hdmi, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad T460 (Intel® Core™ i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4; Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2); Gnome 3.28.2) with dual boot (Ubuntu + Windows-10) and dual display (2nd screen via HDMI to a Samsung HDTV). Dual display works fine with Windows-10.

With Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (64bit; kernel 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu), dual display is faulty: only the desktop background, icons and mouse pointer get displayed on the external display, but not the Unity icons on the left side nor the top bar (activities, date, network, sound, battery, settings, shutdown (...) buttons. This makes the system unusable. As soon as the HDMI cable is disconnected, everything returns to normal (single screen).

Any suggestion to solve this issue is welcome... I could also post the output of other terminal commands if this would help.

Output of Inxi -f

```
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-6300U (-MT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
           clock speeds: max: 3000 MHz 1: 1729 MHz 2: 734 MHz 3: 802 MHz
           4: 761 MHz

           CPU Flags: 3dnowprefetch abm acpi adx aes aperfmperf apic arat
           arch_perfmon art avx avx2 bmi1 bmi2 bts clflush clflushopt cmov
           constant_tsc cpuid cpuid_fault cx16 cx8 de ds_cpl dtes64 dtherm dts
           epb ept ept_ad erms est f16c flexpriority flush_l1d fma fpu
           fsgsbase fxsr hle ht hwp hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_notify ibpb
           ibrs ida intel_pt invpcid invpcid_single lahf_lm lm mca mce
           md_clear mmx monitor movbe mpx msr mtrr nonstop_tsc nopl nx pae pat
           pbe pcid pclmulqdq pdcm pdpe1gb pebs pge pln pni popcnt pse pse36
           pti pts rdrand rdseed rdtscp rep_good rtm sdbg sep smap smep smx ss
           ssbd sse sse2 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 stibp syscall tm tm2 tpr_shadow
           tsc tsc_adjust tsc_deadline_timer vme vmx vnmi vpid x2apic xgetbv1
           xsave xsavec xsaveopt xsaves xtopology xtpr
```

Output of lshw -c video

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:c0000000-dfffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Output of lsmod | egrep ‘i915’:

```
sudo lsmod | egrep 'i915'
i915                 1937408  24
drm_kms_helper        180224  1 i915
drm                   483328  16 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
video                  49152  2 thinkpad_acpi,i915
```

Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5280 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1440x810+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02 +  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00*   59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1872mm x 1053mm
   3840x2160     30.00*+  25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   4096x2160     30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: You can set the launcher on the left side to appear on one screen only or on all screens. Do this in System Settings.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I managed to move the mouse pointer across screens because display setting was on "joint displays". The Isolved the rest of the problem by tweaking system settings: devices/dock section (autohide off, show on all displays), then the devices/display/mirror section. This settles the topic for me, and hopefully for other users in future.